# Using Supertest with Mocha with a consistent base api url

Tags: javascript, node.js, supertest, superagent

I'm trying to use Supertest for the first time against an actual API, not an express app or mock. My understanding is that this syntax should work:

```js
const request = require('supertest')('https://my-api.com');

describe('Obtain a new customer', function() {
  it('responds with json', function(done) {
    request
      .post()
      .send({
        customer_id: '7ewISN7dekjkdn',
        client_password: 'password123'
      })
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.body)
        done()
      })
  });

});
```

In the `.post()` it is giving an `Unresolved function or method post()` error.  I am unclear why.

I understand Superagent is leveraged under the hood.

Can anyone give me a pointer as to the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's just missing to set the path inside the method. For the root just set '/'.

```
const request = require('supertest')('https://my-api.com');

describe('Obtain a new customer', function() {
  it('responds with json', function(done) {
    request
      .post('/')
      .send({
        customer_id: '7ewISN7dekjkdn',
        client_password: 'password123'
      })
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.body)
        done()
      })
  });

});
```

Comment: no it's still seen as 'undefined' - see the updated screenshot

Comment: Your snippet question is different, in the screenshot your mistake is that you shouldn't set the url when you require the supertest --> request = require('supertest');